# Drupal Ubercart how to get cart total?

Tags: php, drupal-7, ubercart

I used Ubercart module for my shopping cart site. I want to get the cart total on the checkout page? I research on google but I can't able to find any proper help for getting the cart total.

I used below code but it returns empty.

http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart%21uc_cart%21uc_cart.module/function/uc_cart_block_view/7

```
$data = uc_cart_block_view();
print_r($data);
```

Please help me how can I get the cart total on check out page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a native ubercart function. However you can peek inside the uc_cart_checkout() function to see how the total is displayed on the checkout page.

I created my own function to do this based on the method used in uc_cart_checkout:

```
function mycustommodule_uc_cart_total($oid = NULL){
  $items = uc_cart_get_contents($oid);
  $subtotal = 0;
    if (is_array($items) && count($items) > 0) {
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $data = module_invoke($item->module, 'uc_cart_display', $item);
        if (!empty($data)) {
          $subtotal += $data['#total'];
        }
      }
    }
    return $subtotal;
}//end function
```

Note, this only tallies the cart item totals and does not include things like shipping or other additional line items.